# no response in jmeter View Results Tree

Tags: jmeter

For the following GET request:

```
GET https://tt.abc.com/mp/getCommunicationProofStatus.form?cacheStamp=1485542553907&rerun_on_error=true&proofId=12345&communicationId=13959&tk=4c3a6859
```

Cookie Data:

```
JSESSIONID=VUsh3HvVhTxho3R52QgH+i9P; tenant=Provider
```

Request Headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest, ABC Customized OWASP CSRFGuard Project
tk: 4c3a6859
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://tt.abc.com/mp/communication/communication_content_edit.form?tk=4c3a6859-a0754305-e173f2b6-870d3589&communicationId=13959
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Host: tt.abc.com
```

I see the following response in firebug:

```
{"is_print_touchpoint":true,"is_pre_proof":true,"item_id":13403,"generated_date":"Feb 02, 2017","job_id":13405,"pre_proof_id":13403,"status":"in_process"}
```

However, there is no response in Jmeter View Results Tree

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to guess the reason, you need at least add a couple of screenshots demonstrating your test plan structure, failing [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener on Sampler Data tab.

Blind shot: you have missing or improperly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), see request parameters highlighted below:

> tt.abc.com/mp/getCommunicationProofStatus.form?cacheStamp=**1485542553907**&rerun_on_error=true&proofId=12345&communicationId=**13959**&tk=**4c3a6859**

- `1485542553907` - looks like a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (evening of Friday, 27th of Jan 2017)
- `13959` - most probably Id of the form, you're trying to submit
- `4c3a6859` - maybe a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token

If you properly handle these parameters I believe the issue will go away